# How to change array into (m x n) array

Tags: javascript

How to change an array (vector) for instance `[1, 2,...,16]` into `[[1,2,3,4],..., [13, 14, 15, 16]]`. I wrote

```
function IntoMatrix(m,n, array){
temp = [];
Temp = [];
for (j=0; j<array.length; j+=m){
  for (i=0; i<n; i++){
   temp.push(array[i+j]);
    }
    Temp.push(temp);
  }
  return Temp;
}
```

but for sure something is wrong. Do you think that I should use `concat` instead of `push` method in `Temp`?

Comment: `temp` and `Temp`? brave

Comment: Let me point out that accessing square arrays is largely just an exercise in determining the right index for a linear array.  In row major order, the index is `row * number_of_columns_per_row + column`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what a function that takes both `m` and `n` should do if `m * n` is not equal to the length of the original array. For example, asking for a 5x10 matrix from an array of 16 elements makes no sense.

Since `n` is dependent on `m` and `arr.length`, I would suggest just taking the inner length (`m`) and outputting the rows that fit. You can do this with a single loop and `slice`:

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]

function matrix(arr, m){
    let res = []
    for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i+=m){
        res.push(arr.slice(i, i+m))
    }
    return res
}
console.log(matrix(arr, 4))  // 4 * 4
console.log(matrix(arr, 2))  // 2 * 8
```

Answer (score 2):

For every internal for loop, you need to reset `temp=[]`.

```js
function IntoMatrix(m,n, array){
temp = [];
Temp = [];
for (j=0; j<array.length; j+=m){
temp = [];
    for (i=0; i<n; i++){
     temp.push(array[i+j]);
        }
        Temp.push(temp);
    }
    return Temp;
}

console.log(IntoMatrix(4,4,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to push cells onto row arrays and rows onto the result array. Row size is determined by the square root of the length of the input by default argument and can be adjusted.

It's not clear that two number parameters are necessary; one parameter to specify row size is sufficient.

```js
const toMatrix = (a, n=a.length**0.5) => 
  a.reduce((m, e, i) => {
    if (i % n === 0) {
      m.push([]);
    }

    m[m.length-1].push(e);
    return m;
  }, [])
;

console.log(toMatrix([...Array(16).keys()].map(e => ++e)));
console.log(toMatrix([...Array(9).keys()].map(e => ++e)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Array.from` method and get the element with current value of `cols * i + j`

```js
function IntoMatrix(rows, cols, array) {
  return Array.from(Array(rows), (e, i) => {
    return Array.from(Array(cols), (el, j) => {
      return array[cols * i + j]
    })
  })
}

const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
console.log(JSON.stringify(IntoMatrix(3, 4, arr)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(IntoMatrix(4, 5, arr)))
```